# When trying to export a team set (5 projects) in a C++ eclipse workspace the project list is empty

Tags: c++, eclipse

Having a Eclipse workspace with 5 C++ projects, I tried to export the team set the project list is empty

Answer (score 0):

Only projects which are checked in with a source control system (SVN, CVS, ...) are included in the projects list.

This is because the Import team set works by checking out the projects from the source control system.